# $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity of $1/\sqrt{x}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am having some trouble showing
$$ \lim_{ x \rightarrow 4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{2}. $$

I chose $\delta$ to be the minimum of $(\frac{2}{1+2\epsilon})^2 - 4$ and $ 4 - (\frac{2}{1-2\epsilon})^2$. It works and was inspired by a picture, but I feel there is an easier trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $\delta=\frac{4}{(2\varepsilon +1)^2}$. Then, if $|x-4|<\delta$, then $\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac 12\right|$ = $\left|\frac{2-\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}\right|<\varepsilon$ holds because $2<\sqrt{x}(2\varepsilon+1)$. You get this last inequality via the triangle inequality.

Comment: Don't you mean $|x^{-1/2} - 1/2|$?

Comment: @nbubis: Indeed, I found a delta for x->16, not x->4, but the reasoning is the same. I'll edit out my answer.